# Is Google Sheets, is there a way to dynamically reference a sheet name in a VLOOKUP statement?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with sheets each representing a week. I'm trying to get my column VLOOKUP to pull in the previous sheet automatically. Currently, I have a statement that looks like this:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'1017'!$A$1:$I$150,6,FALSE),0)
```

but I have to change the '1017' each time I enter the next week's data. I wrote a script that returns the name of the previous sheet, but I can't figure out how to integrate it into the VLOOKUP statement.

```
function getPreviousSheet() {
  previousSheetIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getIndex() - 2;
  sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  previousSheetName = sheets[previousSheetIndex].getName();
  return previousSheetName;
}
```

Comment: `````INDIRECT`````

Comment: I've tried this, but =IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT(getPreviousSheet())!$A$1:$I$150,6,FALSE),0) doesn't seem to work (results in a formula parse error) -- is there any additional massaging I need to do?

Comment: `INDIRECT(getPreviousSheet()&"!$A$1:$I$150")`